# Remove Event listener on initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**EDIT** Solved by using jQuery's `.on()` method and removing the event via `.off()` and `.unbind()`.

---

I have a simple Drag and Drop upload system. Everything works fine until I reinitialize my functions. Problem is that after my second initialization events are still binded after I tried to unbind them before.

I would like to keep the way I add event listeners, just want to remove the old before adding new.

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLysx367/12/) for example (try to drag and drop some file inside the black box). You can see that the `console.log()` is runned twice after reinitialization.

```js
function init() {
  console.log('init')
  var dropZone = $('.dropZone');
  var dropZoneEvent = dropZone.get(0);

  function dragEnter(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('drag enter');
  }

  function dragOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    
  }

  function dragLeave(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('drag leave');
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("drop");
  }

 dropZoneEvent.removeEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
  dropZoneEvent.removeEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  dropZoneEvent.removeEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
  dropZoneEvent.removeEventListener('drop', drop, false);

  dropZoneEvent.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
  dropZoneEvent.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  dropZoneEvent.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
  dropZoneEvent.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
}

init();

$(document).on('click', '.reinit', function() {
  init();
});
```

```css
.dropZone {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
}
.reinit{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropZone"></div>
<div class="reinit">Click me to reinit</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your event functions are in the `init` inner scope. And every time you run `init` these functions are not pointed to the same reference.
Get these functions out of the `init` and put them in global scope and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, how can I pass a variable and event to these functions if they are out of the init inner scope?

Comment: I am sorry but this actually didn't help me. I had to use jQuery's `.on` method and unbind the events via `.unbind()` and `.off()`.